# Trouble JsonObject Parsing cannot converted to jsonarray

Tags: android, json

**Hi**. 
I have a line of json data @ my webservice. All Json data is available at this format, only URL and a link. so its a JsonObject as I know. Short said I request and the result always ends with a url. So output is :

```
{"Url":"www.google.com"}
```

**This what I have done**

```
            JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

            try {
                ListBasedList.clear();
                //for each loop til JSON data
                   for(int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);

                    String json_url = c.getString(TAG_Url);

                    if(json_url.equals(0) && json_url.equals(""))
                    {
                         LinearLayout lin_footer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.footer_layoutMain);
                         lin_footer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put(TAG_Url, json_url);

                    ListBasedList.add(map);
                   }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("JSON Parser fejl", "fejl da man prøve og hente data fra server " + e.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }
```

**Error happening here**

logcat telling me this :

JSONObject cannot be converted to jsonarray

So How I can have the link instead of the error?

**Update #1 --> Logcat full Error**

```
    10-01 13:34:45.685: E/JSON Parser(24256): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value {"url":"www.google.com"} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

**Update #2 --> JsonParser class**

```
public class JSONParser {
    static InputStream is = null;
    static String json = "";
    JSONArray jsonarr=null;
    // konstruktor
    public JSONParser() {
    }

    public JSONArray getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
         JSONArray jsonarr=null;

         // HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // json array paser til string
          try {
                jsonarr = new JSONArray(json);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // retunerer json object tilbage
        return jsonarr;
        }
         }
```

Comment: Post your json response.

Comment: {"Url":"www.google.com"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a single Json object from response. As `{"Url":"www.google.com"}` is a JSONObject.

So the line

```
JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
```

should be as

```
JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
```

And while reading the data you only need

```
String json_url = json.getString(TAG_Url);
```

instead of using for loop.

---

See the updated class

```
public class JSONParser {
    static InputStream is = null;
    static String json = "";
    JSONObject jsonObject = null; // Updated here

    // konstruktor
    public JSONParser() {
    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
        jsonObject = null; // Updated here

        // HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // json array paser til string
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(json); // Updated here
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // retunerer json object tilbage
        return jsonObject; // Updated here
    }
}
```

This will work for your current json. See `// Updated here` to know what I have updated.

Comment: I getting this error : Type mismatch: cannot convert from JSONArray to JSONObject.

Comment: @Tirolel yes you will get. See my updated answer. You need to change for loop logic also.

Comment: @Tirolel Is the given json string is final and correct. Or any more keys are present?

Comment: thank you. Now its working without error. So I think I was mixing object and array together?

Answer (score 1):

What you get is a JSONObject not a JSONArray.

```
 { // represetns json object node 
 "Url":"www.google.com"
 }
```

SO change to

```
  JSONObject jsonobject= jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
```

To parse

```
  String url = jsonobject.getString("Url");
```

Edit:

You need to change this

```
 jsonarr = new JSONArray(json);
```

To

```
 JSONObject job = new JSONObject(json); // considering you get the above json
```

and return

```
 return job;
```

Comment: I getting this error : Type mismatch: cannot convert from JSONArray to JSONObject

Comment: post your full json and post the stack trace

Comment: @Tirolel His answer is right as per the JSON you want to parse. If you haven't posted full JSON then no one can help you out and you should try to understand someone's try and time.

Comment: @PareshMayani yea thats what I done. Now I have updated question.

Comment: @Tirolel if that is your full json there is no need for a loop you can use the above. But if you haven't posted the full json i don't think anyone can help. check the edit

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake in `JSONParser` class where you are returning `JSONArray` and you are trying to get `JSONObeject`. See following code.

```
public class JSONParser {
    static InputStream is = null;
    static String json = "";
    JSONObject jsonarr=null;
    // konstruktor
    public JSONParser() {
    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {// Change return type from `JSONArray` to `JSONObject`
         JSONObject jsonarr=null;

         // HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // json array paser til string
          try {
                jsonarr = new JSONObject(json);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // retunerer json object tilbage
        return jsonarr;
        }
         }
```

Then use following code.

```
JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
```

and

```
String url = json.getString("url");
```